# MUI - React does not recognize the `renderInput` prop on a DOM element in Datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to use the [`DatePicker`](https://mui.com/components/date-picker/#views-playground) component from MUI version 5. I have included it exactly as it is specified in the [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/9lmcq?file=/demo.js:592-662) from the MUI docs. So my component looks like this:

```js
const MonthPicker: FC = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Date | null>(new Date());

    return (
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
            <DatePicker
                views={['year', 'month']}
                label="Year and Month"
                minDate={new Date('2012-03-01')}
                maxDate={new Date('2023-06-01')}
                value={value}
                onChange={(newValue) => {
                   setValue(newValue);
                }}
                renderInput={(props) => <TextField  {...props} size='small' helperText={null} />}
            />
        </LocalizationProvider>
    )
}
```

No matter what I tried, I always got the error message: ***React does not recognize the `renderInput` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `renderinput` instead.***

If I write it in lowercase, then the code doesn't even render. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bug from MUI, you can see it happens in the official docs too when you open the `MonthPicker`. It's because they forgot to filter the `renderInput` callback before passing the rest of the props to the DOM element.

[image]

You can see from the source that the `YearPicker` doesn't have this problem because it [passes every props down manually](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-lab/src/YearPicker/YearPicker.tsx#L172), while the `MonthPicker` chooses to [spread the remaining props](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-lab/src/MonthPicker/MonthPicker.tsx#L134) which includes `renderInput` - this is an invalid prop because the HTML attribute doesn't know anything about JS callback object.

This error is just a warning from ReactJS when it thinks you're doing something wrong, but you're not because this is an upstream bug, and it doesn't affect anything else functionality-wise, so ignore it.

Comment: Active (as of time of writing) issue on MUI's Github: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/28352